# XDMP-REGEX: (err:FORX0002) - String transformation with Regular expressions

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am working on xquery requirement to identify the  xml tag name() from the XML document using the regex.  Later , will do the transformation on data.It searches  the entire document and If i found match, am doing string :replace  using xquery/xpath.

Please find some sample code which am looking for.

```
let $full-doc := fn:doc($uri)
if(fn:matches($full-doc,"<Hyperlink\b[^\>]*?>([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-3]?[0-9] 
[12][890][0-9]{2})</Hyperlink>")) 
then $full-doc 
else "regex is not working"
```

**I am getting the following Error.**

```
regex-match :
[1.0-ml] XDMP-REGEX: (err:FORX0002) fn:matches(fn:doc("44215.xml"), " 
<Hyperlink\b[^\>]*?>([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-3]?[0-9] [12][890][0-9]{2}...") - 
- Invalid regular expression
```

Could some  one please explain why my regex is not working ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your requirement:

> I am working on xquery requirement to identify the xml tag name() from the XML document using the regex.

You are going about this entirely the wrong way. XQuery doesn't see the lexical XML, it sees a tree of nodes. To find the name of an element, use an XPath expression to find the element, then use the `name()` function to get its name.

If you want to find an element whose name matches a regex, use `//*[matches(name(), $regex)]`

Answer (score 2):

The word boundary code `\b` is not supported in XQuery (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#regex-syntax).

But I guess you are looking for `Hyperlink` elements, not for a `<Hyperlink>` substring, so you should use a path expression:

```
let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
where $doc//Hyperlink[matches(., '([A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-3]?[0-9] [12][890][0-9]{2})')]
return $doc
```

Comment: I am looking for both . Also it should match the  data according to the specified regex.

Comment: I also have one more question does  Xquery/Xpath support  \xFF hexa decimal characters ? can you please help me out for the two questions ?

Comment: No, XPath regular expressions do not include \xFF. Use `&#xFF;` instead.

Comment: i know xpath is for traversing the documents . i accidentally had written it.