# Invalid regular expression in Marklogic

Tags: regex, string, marklogic

I am trying to match **stand alone numbers** in some comma separated string , after splitting this string by commas and save it to variable `$i`, I use this regular expression:

```
fn:matches(fn:normalize-space($i), "(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)")
```

- Example : (**123**) should return `true`.
- Example: (**abc123**) sholud return `false`.
- Example: (**abc 123 abc**) should return `false`.

But, it gives me:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-REGEX: (err:FORX0002) .

What is the wrong with this expression?

Comment: `^[0-9]+$` does this help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XDMP-REGEX: (err:FORX0002) - String transformation with Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682460/xdmp-regex-errforx0002-string-transformation-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead and lookbehind are not supported in [XQuery regex](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax) expressions.

However, you don't need them if you are just looking to verify that the value is purely numeric values. You can anchor the expression to the beginning and end of the value and ensure that everything in-between is a number:

```
fn:matches(fn:normalize-space($i), "^\d+$")
```